# Pycharm 4.5.3 remote console 'cannot connect to remote process'

Tags: python, ipython, virtualenv, pycharm

Starting today for no discernible reason, Pycharm's remote console function will not connect with my remote server.

All other functions are working as normal, SSH session, deployment config, skeletons update, file sync etc.
I am running Pycharm 4.5.3 on Windows7x64 against a remote server running Centos6.5x64 on AWS, note that this setup has been working fine for months until today.

The following output appears in the console window when remote console is launched, it takes a minute or so to timeout:

```
sftp://user@FQDN:22/home/user/Envs/lab1/bin/python2.7 -u /home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 0 0
Couldn't connect to console process.
Process finished with exit code -1
```

Unhelpful Log output(C:\Users\user\.PyCharm40\system\log\idea.txt):

```
2015-07-09 17:15:07,910 [ 236325]   INFO - esdk.transport.JschExecProcess - Executing ssh command: env "PYTHONIOENCODING"="UTF-8" "JETBRAINS_REMOTE_RUN"="1" "IPYTHONENABLE"="True" "PYTHONUNBUFFERED"="1" /home/user/Envs/lab1/bin/python2.7 -u /home/user/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevconsole.py 0 0 for user@FQDN:22
```

The following troubleshooting steps have yielded nothing: Workstation / Server, reboot, Fresh Virtualenv, Different version of Python, reinstall of iPython, uninstall of iPython, reset of console / deployment configuration, connecting from a different workstation running same version of Pycharm, upgrade Pycharm from 4.5.2 to 4.5.3.

Suggestions for further troubleshooting steps gladly welcome while I wait for Jetbrains support to get around to my ticket!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was within the security configuration on AWS.

My AWS instance has a friendly FQDN to go with the unfriendly AWS internal name, which appears to cause some havoc with the way their NAT works if you don't have a rule allowing traffic from the IP bound to the FQDN back into the server.
I created the issue yesterday when my office router reset to a new IP - I must've overwritten the recursive rule with the rule allowing my new office IP into the instance.

So, add a rule allowing the server public IP for all traffic and Pycharm connects again when pointed at the FQDN.